How do I use the next value in my counter in hex() while also using sympy in python?
I'm coding in python and I have a small problem. I have a class that increments up by 1 each time it's used. In sympy summations, when a different number is used for the formula, I want to calculate the hex() of the integer that's counted up.
The problem I'm getting is that it's not incrementing up by 1 each time a new value is used in the summations formula. It just uses number 1.
The code I'm using is:
from sympy import symbols, summation,Piecewise,Eq,Mul

x = symbols('0')

class Incrementer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

    def increment(self):
        self.value += 1
        return self.value

def formula(address):

    address0 = int(address,16)
    inc = Incrementer()

    def formula109(b):

        f = b + inc.increment() - b

        formula10 = hex(f)

        d = (int(formula10,16) - b) + b

        return d

    logic = formula109(x)

    expr = Piecewise(
        (logic, Eq(logic,address0)),  # When logic equals m, return logic
        (0, True)  # For all other values of logic, return 0
    )

    total = summation(expr, (x, 1, 89238201021929110))
    print(total)

    return total

As you can see in formula109(), there is a problem in the f variable because while every value in the summation (when you look at the total variable) is being used, it doesn't increment up with each different value. I want it to increment up to the full summation amount which is 89238201021929110 then return the value for each.
The reason I'm using 89238201021929110 is because I'm a fiverr freelancer and my client wants to do some mathematics on analytics but with python automation to make it easier. We need to check the values for all hex strings in ranges 1 - 89238201021929110 because of this and we need to integer value of them all added up like summations do.

Your f= and d= lines don't make a lot of sense. b+incr-b is just incr. You do the same thing on the d= line. Basically b (x proxy) does nothing but waste processes on junk math. You also convert f to a hex but then convert it right back to an int, and never use the hex conversion for anything. Your entire formula109 really does nothing but return increment().

What value does the Incrementer class add to your code? Why not just use an int? Also, please clarify what you're trying to achieve here. What output(s) do you expect for some specific input?
